# Colour changing material/ink

Tags: electricity, visible-light, home-experiment

i am not sure if this is the right place to ask but is it possible for me to make an ink or material that changes colour when electricity goes through it at home? (as much colours as possible and low energy consumption if possible)

Comment: So-called ["smart glass"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_glass#Electrochromic_devices) comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably a material that changes color with heat and have the electric current heat the ink. This is how the meters on the side of batteries work.

[This is the stuff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermochromism) used to make novelty coffee mugs or t-shirts.